# Group array of string arrays with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have array like this, values are string:

```
var arr1 = new [] { "H", "item1", "item2" };
var arr2 = new [] { "T", "thing1", "thing2" };
var arr3 = new [] { "T", "thing1", "thing2" };
var arr4 = new [] { "END", "something" };
var arr5 = new [] { "H", "item1", "item2" };
var arr6 = new [] { "T", "thing1", "thing2" };
var arr7 = new [] { "T", "thing1", "thing2" };
var arr8 = new [] { "END", "something" };

var allArrays = new [] { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8 };
```

I need to group this in to a new array of arrays, so that one array has arrays that start with `H` or `T`. The `END` records (not included in the results) are the delimiters between each section; each new array starts after an `END` array.

In the end I would like to have somethng like this:

```
[
[ [H, item1, item2], [T, thing1, thing2], [T, thing1, thing2] ]
[ [H, item1, item2], [T, thing1, thing2], [T, thing1, thing2] ]
]
```

I know how I can do this with for each loop, but I'm looking for a cleaner way, possibly using linq. All suggestions are much valued, thank you!

Comment: Why LINQ and not a simple loop?

Comment: Can you post the code that can be compilled pls?

Comment: @Serge - have fun

Comment: `I know how I can do this with for each loop` - You need to include that code in your question. Users could then give hints or show how it could be converted to Linq or a Lambda if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/buPYgV

Comment: If you know there's always one `H` and two `T` records plus the `END` terminator, you could use [`IEnumerable.Chunk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) with a size of `4`, and then keep the first three items (`.Take(3)`). Otherwise, there's not an existing link operator that will do what you need (but you can implement your own).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w4yVnZ

Comment: Here's an overload of the `Chunk()` operator that better fits with the spirit of Linq (uses more IEnumerable rather than arrays): https://dotnetfiddle.net/VjskLO. Use it like this: `allArrays.Chunk(a => a[0] == "END", false)`;

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
var newArr = allArrays.Select(a => AddToArr(list, a)).Where(a => a != null);
```

and helper (this code can be put inline, but it easier to read this way)

```
private static string[][] AddToArr(List<string[]> list, string[] arr)
{
    if (arr[0] != "END")
    {
        list.Add(arr);
        return null;
    }
    var r = list.ToArray();
    list.Clear();
    return r;
}
```

result

```
[
[["H","item1","item2"],["T","thing1","thing2"],["T","thing1","thing2"]],
[["H","item3","item4"],["T","thing3","thing4"],["T","thing5","thing6"]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So arr1, arr2, etc are `string[]`.
`allArrays` is a `string[][].`

I hope you gave a meaningful example. From this example it seems that you want all string[] from `allArrays`, except the string[] that have a [0] that equals the word "END".

If this is what you want, your result is:

```
string[][] result = allArrays.Where(stringArray => stringArray[0] != "END");
```

> I need to group this in to a new array of arrays, so that one array has arrays that start with H or T. The END records (not included in the results) are the delimiters between each section; each new array starts after an END array.

This is not exactly the same as I see in your example: what if one of the string arrays in allArrays is an empty array, or if it has the value null values. What if one of the the arrays of strings is empty (= length 0), and what if one of the string arrays doesn't start with "H", nor "T", nor "END"?

Literally you say that you only want the string arrays that start with "H" or "T", no other ones. You don't want string arrays that are null, nor empty string arrays. You also don't want string arrays that start with "END", nor the ones that start with String.Empty, or "A" or "B" or anything else than "H" or "T".

If I take your requirement literally, your code should be:

```
string[] requiredStringAtIndex0 = new string[] {"H", "T"};
string[][] result = allArrays.Where(stringArray => stringArray != null
    && stringArray.Length != 0
    && requiredStringAtIndex0.Contains(stringArray[0]));
```

In words: from allArrays, keep only those arrays of strings, that are not null, AND that have at least one element AND where the element at index 0 contains either "H" or "T"

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use an extension method for grouping runs of items based on a predicate, in this case `GroupByEndingWith` and then throw away the "END" record, like so:

```
var ans = allArrays.GroupByEndingWith(r => r[0] == "END")
                   .Select(g => g.Drop(1).ToArray())
                   .ToArray();
```

But, in general, you can use `Aggregate` to collect items based on a predicate at the expense of comprehension. It often helps to use a tuple to track an overall accumulator and a sub-accumulator. Unfortunately, there is no `+` operator or `Append` for `List<T>` that returns the original list (helpful for expression based accumulation) and since C# doesn't yet have a comma operator equivalent, you need an extension method again or you can use `ImmutableList`.

Using `Aggregate` and `ImmutableList`, you can do:

```
var ans = allArrays.Aggregate(
                (ans: ImmutableList<ImmutableList<string[]>>.Empty, curr: ImmutableList<string[]>.Empty),
                (ac, r) => r[0] == "END"
                                ? (ac.ans.Add(ac.curr), ImmutableList<string[]>.Empty)
                                : (ac.ans, ac.curr.Add(r))
          ).ans
          .Select(l => l.ToArray())
          .ToArray();
```

NOTE: You can also do this with `List` if you are willing to create new `List`s a lot:

```
var ans = allArrays.Aggregate(
                (ans: new List<List<string[]>>(), curr: new List<string[]>()),
                (ac, r) => r[0] == "END"
                                ? (ac.ans.Concat(new[] { ac.curr }).ToList(), new List<string[]>())
                                : (ac.ans, ac.curr.Concat(new[] { r }).ToList())
          ).ans
          .Select(l => l.ToArray())
          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = ConvertToArrayOfArray(arr1, arr2, arr3, arrr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8);
}

private string[][] ConvertToArrayOfArray(params string[][] arrs)
{
    List<string[]> yoList = new List<string[]>();
    arrs.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        if(!x[0] == "END") yoList.Add(x);
    });
    return yoList.ToArray();
}
```